# Streaming a response with django-import-export

Tags: python, django, stream, django-import-export

I've been using django-import-export for a while now to provide CSV/XLS export functionality of data for users but as datasets get larger I'm encountering server timeouts.

I understand it's possible to use `StreamingHttpResponse` but from what I've seen this is done by writing your own CSV writer functions to output your data which, at least initially, doesn't strike me as something I can do with my current approach.

Is it possible to stream a response when you're using a django-import-export model resource to generate your file?

This is the kind of code I've implemented at the moment, with a standard `HttpResponse`;

```
class ExportConsolePlacesView(ClientPlacesView, View):
    """
    Export view for all places, either incomplete or complete.
    """
    model = Place
    http_method_names = ['get', ]

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        console_name = self.console.name.replace(' ', '_')

        if kwargs['query'] == u'complete':
            dataset = PlaceResource().export(
                Place.objects.complete_entrants_for_console(self.console)
            )
            filename = '{}_complete_entrants'.format(console_name).lower()

        elif kwargs['query'] == u'incomplete':
            dataset = PlaceResource().export(
                Place.objects.incomplete_entrants_for_console(self.console)
            )
            filename = '{}_incomplete_entrants'.format(console_name).lower()

        export_type = kwargs['format']
        _dataset_methods = {
            'csv': dataset.csv,
            'xls': dataset.xls
        }
        response = HttpResponse(
            _dataset_methods[export_type], content_type=export_type
        )
        response[
            'Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={fn}.{ext}'.format(
                fn=filename,
                ext=export_type
            )

        return response
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I queried this with the developer of `django-import-export` and he believes that due to the app using `tablib` it wouldn't be possible to stream the response due to the way `tablib` behaves.

> I think it would not be possible to create stream of export from tablib which django-import-export uses.

https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/206

Comment: So basically if you have thousands of rows, you can't use it. Bummer.

Comment: It's been a few years since @s29's comment, but to clarify for anyone reading this, this does not mean that django-import-export is unusable in these instances. For instance, you could put it behind something like Celery.